# Как очистить индивидуальный параметр сохранения настроек?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как очистить параметр типа `string` под именем `SaveGUID`, чтобы при запуске формы, `textBox` не смог отобразить значение этого параметра.

Есть два похожих примера, но они не рабочие. Первый:

```
Settings.Default.PropertyValues["MyPropertyName"].SerializedValue = Settings.Default.Properties["MyPropertyName"].DefaultValue;
Settings.Default.PropertyValues["MyPropertyName"].Deserialized = false;
```

Второй:

```
Settings.Default.SomeSetting = Settings.Default.Properties["SomeSetting"].DefaultValue;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

[*Ссылка на #1*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781494/wpf-application-settings-resetting-a-single-property)

[*Ссылка на #2*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645393/set-project-application-settings-to-defaults)

Comment: Вам нужно очищать значение, сохраненное в пользовательских настройках, или просто его не отображать в `TextBox`?

Comment: Очищать, потому как значения из этого параметра каждый раз берутся при загрузке формы...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При загрузке формы подпишитесь на событие `Form.Load` далее в его обработчике сбросьте значение нужного свойства и сохраните изменения.

```
private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  Сбрасываем значение в empty.
    Settings.Default.PropertyName = string.Empty;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! оказывается все так просто было....

Comment: Пожалуйста, будут вопросы задавайте.